# how do I fix the total amount of pixel used from a grid in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sorry if this is a repeated question and I'd like some help cause I'm a noob.
I created a grid. But every time I enter a different number, it uses a different total amount of pixel. I want the height and the width of the body that contains grid to stay exactly the same size no matter what the number of grid is.

https://moonsol124.github.io/ETCH-A-SKETCH-TOP-PROJECT-/

here is what I made.

java:

```
function createGrid(maxGrid = 16) {
    for (let i = 0; i < maxGrid; i++) {
        const divRow = document.createElement('div');
        divRow.classList.add('div-row');
        for (let j = 0; j < maxGrid; j++) {
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            div.classList.add('div-style');
            divRow.appendChild(div);
        }
        body.appendChild(divRow);
    }
addColorOnGrid();
```

}

css:

```
.div-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.div-style {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: RGB(0, 0, 0);
    border: solid 3px RGB(255, 255, 255);
}
```

html:

```
   <body>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn" id="grid-button">Enter number of grid</button>
            <button class="btn" id="reset-button">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-body">

        </div>
    </body>
```

please tell me if my approach is wrong. thanks for your help.

Comment: - Your question is hard to understand. First the first phrase is just noise, just get to the point. Then "you enter a different number" of what, where ? We should not have to guess. You should be precise.
- The 'body' is a specific element in the DOM. you shouldn't use that word for other element, it is confusing.
- If you want an element to have a specific width or height  (the div with the grid-body class, IIUC), why don't you try to assign it one with css ?

Comment: And also Java is not Javascript.

Comment: @learner Hi, I'm sorry I couldn't find a better way to express myself. Currently if I enter an input through the 'enter number of grid', it does not only change the grid but also the entire size. I want the size of the entire grid to stay the same weather the number of grid is 2 or 99. like this: https://parkercon.github.io/etch-a-sketch/

Comment: Ok now I understand what you want. You should study the code in the last link you gave (just hit Control-U in your browser and click on the js and css files). We can see also (using your browser inspector tools) that when the number of cells change the `grid-template-columns: repeat(22, 2fr); grid-template-rows: repeat(22, 2fr);` properties of the grid container change too. I think this is the way. (the number changing is 22 here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help to you solve your problem I just add these parts

```
divRow.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
document.getElementById('ac').appendChild(divRow);
```

it access the parent alement and create div inside that element

And you can pass any number here to test **onLoad="createGrid(6)"**

```js
function createGrid(maxGrid) {

    for (let i = 0; i < maxGrid; i++) {
    
        const divRow = document.createElement("div");
        divRow.classList.add('div-row');
        
        for (let j = 0; j < maxGrid; j++) {
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            div.classList.add('div-style');
            divRow.appendChild(div);
        }
        
        divRow.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
            document.getElementById('ac').appendChild(divRow);
    }

}

function popup() {

    let val = prompt("Please enter value here"); 
  
    const div = document.getElementsByClassName("div-style");
    
    for(i = 0; div.length > 0; i++){
        div[0].remove()
    }
  
   this.createGrid(parseInt(val));
  
}
```

```css
.grid-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.div-style {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: RGB(0, 0, 0);
    border: solid 3px RGB(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="createGrid(6)">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn" id="grid-button" onClick="popup()">Enter number of grid</button>
            <button class="btn" id="reset-button">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-body" id="ac">

        </div>
    </body>
```